# Clock Sychronization

Tags: c, linux, time, embedded, clock

I am having a setup the has two components: master and slave.
They communicate by uart.
Each of them have RTC (real time clock) module, and I want to sync the slave's RTC with the master's.

I have few questions regarding to my goal. First I want to present my implementation

**A.** I am intending to do as follows:

```
SLAVE SENT TIMESTAMP X to MASTER
MASTER RECEIVES X, and MEASURES TIME Y
MASTER SENDS (X,Y) to SLAVE
CLIENT MEASURE TIME Z and SET RTC TO Z + (Y-X)
```

the explanation for this is that `Z=X+T` where `T` is the time gap that passed, and so, we got that slave RTC is get to be `X+T+Y-X` which is `Y+T` which is also the time on the master

**B.** The built in error in my computation is the half-round-trip-time - i.e the time that it takes the slave measurement to reach the master

**C.** In the ntp rfc, I can see they compute the offset as
  `theta = T(B) - T(A) = 1/2 * [(T2-T1) + (T3-T4)]` (They measure 4 times, please refer to the wiki/rfc), so I understand that they take some sort of average between the first half of the trip time to the second

**D.** My first question: if/how my implementation plan lacks in respect to what is done on ntp. as far as I understand `C` I don't miss anything if I assume that the time gaps between sending and receiving on my system are stable (i.e. `T2-T1 = T3-T4`)

**E.** Second question, do you know if setting an RTC also reset's it's inner counter? (i.e. if you set an rtc to some time when it was on the half way to increment, is the counter reset after set). I wasn't able to find an answer for this question.

**F.** Lastly, I want to sync the RTCs on  precision of few milliseconds, let's say 10ms. and I am wondering how to do so-

In the master I can measure a time stamp that contains nanoseconds, and in the slave I can use the ticks method (tick happens every fixed time amount, let's say every 1ms).

So I thought of maybe do the following change:

On the slave side do the measurement "close" to a full second (i.e. when `TOTAL_TICKS*TICKS_INTERVAL / 1000 < 2`): X

On master I will measure time in milliseconds: Y, and will send X,Y to slave

On slave I will stall for the number of ticks needed to truncate the milliseconds part of Y, and then as before add the difference in seconds (Y.seconds - X) to my RTC.

How does this sounds like?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why can't the master say "this is the time, fall in line"? As for whether UART is suitable or not, that depends on your real-time requirements - it isn't easy to calculate latency on UART unless you somehow can guarantee the time period between bytes. If these are Linux computers I'd probably say forget about it, unless your time resolution is seconds or longer still.

Comment: In your system you can probably calibrate how long it takes to send the message. In NTP they don't know and it isn't exactly the same every time.

Comment: In your system you can pick some time point accurately on both components, such as the beginning of the UART transmission, or the end. Then both components read the time at that point, and adjust their clocks so they read the same at that point. NTP can't do this.

Comment: ok, thanks. does anyone knows about (E)? I thought about another option: I can make sure to set the RTC clock in the same (TOTAL_TICKS % TICKS_IN_SECONDS) to make sure I set the time in the "same time" in milliseconds percision

Comment: actually, I can make that my last suggestion won't be dependent on (E). I can measure the RTC on value V, then set it to V [this will make me independent of(E)], and continue as before. Then when I will do the set to the new time T, I will get what I wanted. what do you think

Comment: Seems over complicated given you only need synchronisation within 10ms.  Say you transmit a 64-bit Unix epoch timestamp in millisecond resolution - that is 8 bytes which takes 694us to transfer at 115200,N,8,1, so you could just transmit the time stamp and set the slave RTC accordingly.  If you like you could even adjust for the transfer time.  Even if somehow you failed to feed the UART to stream the output or used a more verbose timestamp format, you would struggle to not achieve 10ms precision.

Comment: @Clifford but if RTC is being set by seconds, don't I anyway have to use the ticks to find out the correct moment to set the RTC?

Comment: @e.ad : If the slave is given the time in milliseconds then, `milliseconds_to_second_boundary = 1000 - (timestamp % 1000)`, so on receipt of the timestamp, you wait `milliseconds_to_second_boundary` milliseconds and set the clock to `(timestamp + 1000) / 1000` seconds.

Comment: ... or more simply, just ensure the master only provides the synchronisation on the 1 second boundary. Then it need not provide 1ms resolution, you can a 32bit Unix epoch time in seconds that can be generated by `mktime`.  That has just 347us transmit time.

Answer (score 1):

> D. My first question: if/how my implementation plan lacks in respect to what is done on ntp.

The short answer is: You don't compensate for the delay between the system #1 reads its clock (`X`) and system #2 reads its clock (`Y`).

Consider this time line:

```
  X is sampled                  Y is sampled             
     |                             |
  ----------------------------------------> timeline
      \---------- delay ----------/
        time it takes to transfer
          X to the other system
               and read Y
```

Let's call the difference between the clocks on the systems for `theta` and the delay for `D` then you have:

```
X = T1
Y = T2 = T1 + theta + D
Y - X = T2 - T1 =  T1 + theta + D -T1 = theta + D
```

then you set/adjust the clock by adding that result like `Z + (Y - X)` which is `Z + theta + D`, i.e. your adjustment includes the delay `D`. That is a problem with your approach if `D` is high compared to the desired precision.

The ntp formula tries to compensate that delay by assuming that the delay will be the same when going from system #1 to system #2 and when going from system #2 to system #1.

It works like this:

If we make the assumption that the the time it takes from T1 is measured to T2 is mesured, is the the **same as** the time it takes from T3 is measured to T4 is mesured, then the formula

```
theta = T(B) - T(A) = 1/2 * [(T2-T1) + (T3-T4)]
```

will compensate for all the "measurement delay".

Assume a situation where the two systems are perfectly in sync. Then `T2-T1` will be equal to the "measurement delay". Let's call it `Tmd`. Then `T3-T4` will be equal `-Tmd` and you get

```
theta = 1/2 * [(Tmd) + (-Tmd)] = 0
```

Which tells you that the systems are in sync.

If we assume the first system is 100 ticks behind the second system (which has the correct time) you get:

```
T1-T2 = (CorrectTime - 100) + Tmd - CorrectTime = -100 + Tmd
T3-T4 = CorrectTime - (Tmd + CorrectTime - 100) = -Tmd - 100
theta = 1/2 * [-100 + Tmd + -Tmd - 100] = 1/2 * [-200] = -100
```

So again the "measurement delay" has been compensated and you get a precise value of difference between the systems.

Further notice:

> D. ...... if I assume that the time gaps between sending and receiving on my system are stable (i.e. `T2-T1 = T3-T4`)

The formula is wrong. It's easy to see if you considered a state where the two systems are perfectly synchronised. In such a system you will have:

```
T2 = T1 + delay
T4 = T3 + delay
```

inserted in the formula you get:

```
        T2 - T1 = T3 - T4
T1 + delay - T1 = T3 - (T3 + delay)
          delay = -delay
```

which is obviously wrong.

BTW:

When you do the adjustments, you don't adjust in using a single measurement. You put your measurements through a low-pass filter and adjust using the output of the filter.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I guess you assumed that time measurement delay is the same for both directions and on all times?

Comment: @e.ad yes, I wrote that in the start: "If we make the assumption that the the time....". Without that assumption the formula doesn't work. If the delay in the two two direction differs with one being constantly faster than the other, you'll get a permanent offset failure. In networking system that is seldom the case.

Comment: sry for not specifying, my question was regarding to the detailed example where it seemed to be unrelated to the initial declaration

Comment: @e.ad In D you ask what you are missing. I tried to explain that you are missing the compensation for the time between measurements. I have edited the answer to make that more clear. If it's still not what your asking, please explain in more details.

Comment: Yes, I know that what you came to answer of, there was a misunderstanding because of my first comment on your post. I understand that you indeed in my computation I preserve the error of the time the information travels, but it's fine in my case. However, I want to ask you- if the NTP computation compensates for this time only when the time travel is the same for both directions, then how then can make this assumption? over the net the time travels are not symmetric at all

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like the [AUTOSAR TimeSync over CAN (R22-11 SWS)](https://www.autosar.org/fileadmin/standards/classic/22-11/AUTOSAR_SWS_TimeSyncOverCAN.pdf) could be used similar over UART. AUTOSARs timesync is an adaption of IEEE 802.1AS and the linked document an adaption to CAN and its priority based arbitration. Advantage of CAN over your UART is though, that a FullCAN mailbox can be assigned to a TimeSync message, where on UART, you might have to interpret first, if the received data content is a timesync or whatever else, as an overhead to take the local time.

The SYNC protocol itself is hierarchical top-down, and on CAN it does not use the Pdelay measurement part at all:

1. TimeMaster transmits the SYNC message, with the seconds part (sec(t0r)) of the time (t0r).
2. This is the closest on CAN of a sync point, where TimeMaster sees a transmitted message and TimeSlaves see a reception

2a. TimeMaster takes internal time on TxConfirmation of SYNC (t1r)

2b, TimeSlaves take internal time on RxIndication of SYNC (t2r)

3. TimeMaster transmits a FUP (FollowUp) message with the nanoseconds part of the time from SYNC TxConfirmation (t4r=t1r-sec(t0r)).
4. TimeSlaves can calculate the time at t3r after reception of FUP according to t = (t3r - t2r) + (sec(t0r) + t4r)

see also in ch. 1 of the linked file the diagram.

Comment: The thing about CANbus and indeed any _network_ is they have multiple nodes, access arbitration, buffering and priority schemes, and even bridges, switches and other intermediate nodes that make timing less deterministic.  In this case with a direct UART connection between two nodes, this complexity is not needed to provide time synchronisation.